# What is the systemd equvalent to sysvinit 'X-Start-Before'?

Tags: boot, systemd, dependencies, init

Quoted from https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts.

> X-Start-Before: boot_facility_1 [boot_facility_2...]
>
> X-Stop-After: boot_facility_1 [boot_facility_2...]
>
> provide reverse dependencies, that appear as if the listed facilities had should-start and should-stop on the package with these headers.

What is the systemd equvalent to sysvinit `X-Start-Before`?

Similar to systemd's `Before=`, but stronger, as a dependency.

Comment: Could you be more precise about what is missing from the `Before=` and `After=` directives in systemd?

Comment: `Before=` and `After=` do not fail. The service will be load whether the systemd units listed under `Before=` or `After=` actually exist.

If we compare this to systemd `Requires=`, if the activation fails, the unit will be deactivated. Systemd's `Requires=` is similar to sysvinit's `Required-Start`.

I am looking for the systemd equvalent to sysvinit `X-Start-Before`.

Comment: Are the `WantedBy=` and `RequiredBy=` options in the `[Install]` section what you're looking for?